# Reactjs undefined issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add the data of my api to my other file, it's related to covid-19 virus and want to add three different sections, confirmed, recovered an deaths.

My code  file with data(api)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const API = 'https://covid19.mathdro.id/api';

class MyData extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      confirmed: 0,
      recovered: 0,
      deaths: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(API)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({
        confirmed: data.confirmed.value,
        deaths: data.deaths.value,
        recovered: data.recovered.value }));
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <worldInfo data={this.state.confirmed} />,
      <worldInfo data={this.state.recovered} />,
      <worldInfo data={this.state.deaths} />
    )
  }
}

export default MyData;
```

The other file where I'm trying to use the data.

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: 'Confirmed',  female: confirmed, male: 2290,
  },
  {
    name: 'Recovered', female: 125000, male: 2000,
  },
  {
    name: 'Deaths ', female: 25000, male: 0,
  },
];
```

The error I get is **'confirmed' is not defined  no-undef**

Comment: How do you get confirmed in this "other file"? Do you import it somehow?
You may for example to write a function that returns that data, like: function getData(confirmed) { const data = [ ... ]; return data; } and put this function in the componentDidMount with your api call. So, in your example it's not clear how "confirmed" variable gets into the file with data.

Comment: I import it with react

Comment: could you complete your code with this import and the place where you export it?

Comment: `MyData` looks okay. Can you pos full error message and show the code where you use `data`. It might be that you are doing something like this: `data.map(..` where `confirmed` doesn't exists as a key. Also `female: confirmed` - looks like an error because what is female: confirmed there? variable? Other objects have differnt signature: `female: 125000`